# Get value which occurred the most for an id in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame with several ids, every id has a category. My result should contain the category which occurred the most for a certain id.

Example:

```
id  categorie
1   aaa
1   aaa
2   bbb
2   bbb
2   aaa
3   aaa
3   ccc
3   ccc
```

Result:

```
id  categorie
1   aaa
2   bbb
3   ccc
```

I tried several .groupby() approaches but none have worked so far.

Comment: ``df.groupby("id").categories.max()`` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
df = df.groupby(by=['id'], as_index=False)['categorie'].max()
```

Or:

```
df = df.groupby(by=['id'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])
print(df)

   id categorie
0   1       aaa
1   2       bbb
2   3       ccc
```